# RestAssured strage behaviour with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, rest-assured

**Problem statement** - Path-params sent from RestAssured test case received as null.
An API definition like,

```
@RequestMapping("myapp")
public interface MyApi {

    @GetMapping(path = "getItem/{path1}/{path2}/{path3}")
    public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> getItem(@PathVariable("path1") String path1,
        @PathVariable("path2") String path2, @PathVariable("path3") String path3);
}

@RestController
public class MyController implements MyApi {

    public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> getItem(String path1, String path2, String path3) {
        return myService.delegateToMethod(path1, path2, path3);
    }

}
```

This setup fine and gives result.
Functional-test code described in short
**Part of Test class code**

```
@Test
public void getItemTest() {
    MyResponse response = apiStub.callGetItem("1","2","3");
    Assert.notNull(response);
}
```

**Part of Stub class**

```
public MyResponse callGetItem(String param1, String param2, String param3) {
    return given().port(servicePort)
        .pathParam("path1", param1)
        .pathParam("path2", param2)
        .pathParam("path3", param3)
        .when().get("/myapp/getItem/{path1}/{path2}/{path3}")
        .then().statusCode(200)
        .extract()
        .as(MyResponse.class);
}
```

**Observation** Test assertion fails. By putting debug point in controller class, I see path-values are being received as null
**What's Interesting** If I put API definition directly in controller, it works !!
**DISCLAIMER** Code is kept short for brevity, shall expand on sections as requested.
**Request** If duplicate question or bug, request re-direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `@RestController` on API definition as well as the implementing controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("myapp")
public interface MyApi {

    @GetMapping(path = "getItem/{path1}/{path2}/{path3}")
    public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> getItem(@PathVariable("path1") String path1,
        @PathVariable("path2") String path2, @PathVariable("path3") String path3);
}
```

**UPDATE** Root-Cause was spring-boot version. I was using old version(`2.0.8.RELEASE`). Segregation of API and Controller, as described does not work. Such end-point results as,

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/getItem/{path1}/{path2}/{path3}?path1=v1&path2=v2&path3=v3
```

Same code, upgraded to spring-boot version `2.4.5`, worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your params values in the Map object and pass it to `.pathParams(Map map)` method instead of invoking the same method multiple times.